# Don't show my ListView with custom adapter in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a problem with show a listView with custom adapter in my Fragment, this code works in a activity but don't in my fragment, when I run my code don't show any errors. 
Again, this code works in a activity, show the listView correctly with the adapter and show a Toast with each data obtained from JsonObjectRequest but in a Fragment don't show only the listView but show the Toast correctly. I set the background color of the fragment to red but this show a white screen and the Toast.(Sorry for my bad english).

```
public class ComplaintsFragment extends Fragment {
ListView lstCategories;
private RequestQueue queue;
private String url="http://192.168.1.3:8000/api/tipos";
private ArrayAdapter<CategoriaModel> categoriaAdapter;
List<CategoriaModel> categories;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complaints, 
    container, false);
    queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(view.getContext());
    categories=new ArrayList<>();
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Hello you're Fragment", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    lstCategories=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategories);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new 
    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new 
    Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    int idcategory=jsonObject.getInt("idcategory");
                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    String details= jsonObject.getString("details");
                    CategoriaModel category=new 
                    CategoriaModel(idcategory,name,details);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), 
                    category.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    categories.add(category);
                }
                categoriaAdapter=new 
                CategoriaAdapter(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,categories);
                lstCategories.setAdapter(categoriaAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return view;
 }
}
```

This is my Adapter for listView

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoriaModel> {
    public CategoriaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<CategoriaModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            CategoriaModel objItem=getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View contenedor=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category,parent,false);
            TextView lblNombre=contenedor.findViewById(R.id.lblNombre);
            TextView lblDescripcion=contenedor.findViewById(R.id.lblDescripcion);
            lblNombre.setText(objItem.getNombre());
            lblDescripcion.setText(objItem.getDescripcion());
            return contenedor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an activity which you add the fragment to?

Comment: Yes, in a activity from Nav activity, I create a FrameLayout with id=fragment_container and use on the function NavigationItemSelect getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new ComplaintsFragment()).commit(); this run when select the item from nav view.

Comment: Who you be able to provide a screenshot of the screen. You say the toasts work. So does that mean a listview does appear but it is blank?

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks for your time @noyanc.

Comment: Also your are using your own view for the items in list therefore dont need to pass in android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. You are using your own one item_category. So remove that and also correct the constructor and super by removing resource.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new ComplaintsFragment()).commit();
```

with this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.content,new ComplaintsFragment()).commit();
```

All works, problem solved

Comment: Okay. Can you add the xml that has the fragment container. Because it should work with that too. Have you set the correct height for the fragment container to be visible.